# Google Maps API v3 - Minor distortion (white/gray stripes)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I set up a Google Maps v3 at our website at http://wallawalla.tk/services and I encounter a minor distortion issue. That is, if you look at the map very precisely, you'll see that there are random "white/gray stripes" appearing. Most important at the very left side of the map and especially when opening InfoWindows respectively closing them. It appears that "white/gray stripes" are somehow related to the border of the InfoWindow, i.e. it seems that if one of the borders doesn't show up (most of the time at the very left side of the respective InfoWindow), there is a random "white/gray stripe" appearing near or even through the InfoWindow. Unfortunately this isn't reproducible 100% of the time which makes it even more suspicious to me. Please try to open/close some of the InfoWindows to actually see it. I guess it is somehow related to our CSS. I read a lot about related distortions but nothing seem to fit my specific case. The "white/gray stripe" on the very left side of the map itself is reproducible almost 100% of attempts trying to reproduce. All "white/gray stripes" are 1px in width and they disappear if you either pan the map or scroll it out and back into the viewport of the Browser window. I'm testing with Google Chrome 22.0.1229.79/Webkit.

Doesn't seem to affect FF11.0/Gecko. Tried it just yet and while Chrome shows described behaviour, FF doesn't

Comment: My guess is that it is being caused by OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier. Can you build a simple test that displays your points and InfoWindows without using OMS and see if you still have the issue?

Comment: You're awesome! I guess looking for too long on a certain task somehow  makes you routine-blinded. As a workaround I now explicitly request v3.7 of the Google Maps API (btw as recommended by OMS maintainer) and it just works! Thanks a million looking at it!

Comment: No problem. I added my comment as an answer so you could close this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it is being caused by OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier. Can you build a simple test that displays your points and InfoWindows without using OMS and see if you still have the issue?